# how to install gdbm on openwrt

Tags: openwrt, gdbm

I never used openwrt before but now I need to install gdbm package on openwrt. Could you please suggest me how to do it.

Make is not working on openwrt

Downloading gdbm sources and compiling them is giving me when configuring

configure: error: in `/HDD/gdbm-1.13':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See`config.log' for more details

Please help me

Comment: Show up `config.log` please

Answer (score 0):

Follow the openwrt guide to get and build the [openwrt from source](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/build)

In make menuconfig, select the gdbm package and then start the compilation. It's pretty simple.

Comment: gdbm package is not available from menuconfig.

Comment: It's available in the master branch of openwrt https://github.com/openwrt/packages/tree/master/libs/gdbm.
Make sure you are using the same version of Openwrt and then copy the Makefile from the above source to openwrt/package/libs/gdbm directory, then fire "make menuconfig".